# linear algebra subspaces question

Tags: linear-algebra

Let there be $V_1$ and $V_2$ subspaces of vector space $V$. Prove that:

if $\dim(V_1+V_2)= 1+ \dim(V_1 \cap V_2)$, then $V_1+V_2$ is one of the subspaces and $V_1 \cap V_2$ is the other.

help with this question and a detailed explanation, if possible, would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to post what you have done so far to show that you put some effort into solving this problem.

Comment: I do not know how to approach this question...or why else do you think I'm here for?

Comment: hint: If you take a basis for $V_1\cap V_2$, and add one basis element, you already get a basis for $V_1\oplus V_2$.

Comment: hint continued: A basis for $V_1 + V_2$ can be obtained by the already mentioned basis elements for $V_1\cap V_2$, then the basis elements belonging only to $V_1$, and finally the basis elements only belonging to $V_2$.

Comment: @abatkai you should be careful not to confuse $\oplus$ and $+$

Comment: @MTurgeon: sorry, you are of course right. $\oplus$ should be $+$ above.

Comment: a base for V1 intersection V2 can be described as that of V1 or that of V2 right? So I can actually choose whatever base I want?

Comment: and if they are different in size? will the base of the intersection will be of the smaller or the larger of the two bases?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to use that $\dim(V_1+V_2)=\dim V_1+\dim V_2-\dim(V_1\cap V_2)$, so $1+\dim(V_1\cap V_2)=\dim V_1+\dim V_2-\dim(V_1\cap V_2)$ and therefore
$2 \dim(V_1\cap V_2)=\dim V_1+\dim V_2-1$.
Now show that if $\dim(V_1\cap V_2)<\dim V_1$ and $\dim(V_1\cap V_2)<\dim V_2$, this gives a contradiction.

Comment: the two last demands you stated here are automatically true since we know V1 does not equal V2, for if they were it would have led to a contradiction in the main equality of this problem (0=1).Im not sure how you get a contradiction out of those two last demands though?

Comment: If the last two inequalities hold, then $\dim(V_1\cap V_2)\leq \dim V_1-1$ and $$\dim(V_1\cap V_2)\leq\dim V_2-1$. Does this help?

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, I now understand.